# using unique rule of laravel 4 on updating database records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

i have this table weapons that have the columns weaponID, weaponName, wStock, wDesc

in my update function inside the controller, i have this set of rules

```
public function c_updateSystemUser($id)
{
    $rules = array(
            'weaponName'  => 'required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/|unique:weaponTbl,weaponName,' . $id,
            'wStock'      => 'required|numeric',
            'wDesc'       => 'required|min:1|max:100|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/' 

        );
    //other stuff
}
```

when i updated and only changed the wStock it is having problems because it is saying that the weaponName already existed. so i used the unique rule

```
unique:weaponTbl,weaponName,' . $id,
```

because i wanted to except the record whose im currently working on but when i tested it i'am having these errors

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `weaponTbl` where `weaponName` = unicorn and `id` <> 1)
```

why is that it using id only whereas i don't have any 'id' in my table but only weaponID? is there a way to work around with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your weapon class you need to change the primary key:

```
class Weapon extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'weaponID';

}
```

And then change the unique rule to:

```
unique:weaponTbl,weaponName,' . $id . ',weaponID'
```

Comment: Still had the same error here is my weapon model class 

`<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Weapon extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
 public $timestamps = false;
 protected $primaryKey = 'weaponID';
 protected $table = 'weaponTbl;

 protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
`

Comment: Hmm... try changing the unique rule to `unique:weaponTbl,weaponName,' . $id . ',weaponID'`

Comment: No problem, I'll edit the answer to include the found solution.